# Local Network Chat between Ubuntu and OS X with Terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

I was trying to create a chat between two computers on the same network, through terminal. The difficulty is that Comp2 is OS X, while mine, Comp1 is Ubuntu.

We want to do it through terminal, as it is similar between the two operating systems (I think it is too different to work, though. But why not ask.)

We tried to use netchat as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61995/chat-over-lan-from-linux-to-linux), but we failed.

Is there a way to chat between OS X and Ubuntu using terminal?

If so, how?

If not, what is the simplest, lowest resource way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a script for each side of it. Using Python by importing socket, using s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) and then using s.connect and s.send . On the other computer I had a similar script to receive the answers. You can see the code here -  client side files folder has the 'receive' code and raspberry pi folder has the sending code under TCP.

https://github.com/EmoryTechlab/visitorDetector