# Is it possible to ping a remote Linux machine without using ssh?

Tags: ssh, remote-access, ping

I am trying to poke/ping a remote Linux machine without using `ssh`. Is there any other utilities to do this?

Addition: It would be quite a lot of helpful if poke can be done without providing the remote machine's password. Is it possible?

---

Update: I came to know about `write` and `wall` tools. Anybody know how to use them?

Comment: `ping <remote>` does not work?

Comment: I want to know the remote user that I have poked him/her. That't why I used the term `poke` in question. :)

Comment: You want to trigger a message to pop up on the remote machine? You might want to look into the answers to these questions, although I have no idea whether they work beyond a local network: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61995/chat-over-lan-from-linux-to-linux http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99460/sending-messages-to-another-user

Comment: I edited my answer to use `wall`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`knockd` may be your answer.

#### Server part:

---

1. Install `knockd` --> `sudo apt-get install knockd`
2. Edit configuration file --> `sudo nano /etc/knockd.conf` also you can use `gedit` or `vi`.
3. The configuration file should look like this after the edit:

   ```
   [options]
           LogFile     = /var/log/knockd.log
           Interface   = wlan0
   [sendMessage]
           sequence    = 1111,2222
           seq_timeout = 5
           command     = /usr/bin/env sh -c "echo 'Hello, World' | wall"
           tcpflags    = syn
   ```

   Where `Interface` is the listening network interface, `sequence` is the port knocking sequence and `command` is the command to be executed when knocked.
4. Edit startup file --> `sudo nano /etc/default/knockd`
   In this file you only need to change `START_KNOCKD=0` to `START_KNOCKD=1`
5. Reload `knockd` to apply changes with `sudo /etc/init.d/knockd reload`

#### Client part:

---

Simply telnet in that order the server ports and the command will be executed

```
telnet MYSERVER 1111
telnet MYSERVER 2222
```

You can also use the `knock` utility:

```
knock MYSERVER 1111 2222
```

#### Final notes

---

- You can also view those connections in the `Logfile` specified, (i.e. `/var/log/knockd.log`)
- You can use a more complex port combination (i.e. `5555,5050,3333,3030`)
- You can read the entire documentation at the [developer's webpage](http://www.zeroflux.org/projects/knock)
- You can read a great tutorial on the [ubuntu community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortKnocking)

Answer (score 2):

You can try `nc` (netcat) to send/receive any messages (files too) over the network.

For example the computer A has IP address 192.168.1.10 and computer B has IP address 192.168.1.20.

At first open a port on computer A to which the computer B will connect to:

```
$ nc -l 2000
```

Now Computer A will listen for incoming connections on port 2000, you should use any port other than "0-1023" i.e. well known ports.

Now we will make a connection from computer B to the port 2000 of computer A:

```
$ nc 192.168.1.10 2000
```

Now the computers will be connected and you can write any message from computer A which will be displayed on computer B and vice versa.

Comment: you are always amazing brother.

Comment: @Ten-Coin Thanks for you kind comment. Glad I could help :)