# How to build a simple chat using netcat?

Tags: command-line, networking, c++, netcat

I am currently working on a project and I have implemented a simple chat application using the `netcat` libraries.

The client is prompted to enter port number and the command

```
nc -l -p xxxx
```

where `xxxx` is the port number entered by the client.

Similarly, the host is prompted for the same port number and a connection is established using

```
nc <ip_address> -p xxxx
```

However, this gives a blank chat experience as it does not show the username of the person typing the messages, something like

```
hey
hello
what's up
Nothing
```

Instead, I want it to be something like,

```
Foo : hey
Boo : hello
Foo : what's up
Boo : Nothing
```

Can I use `netcat` to achieve this functionality or is there anything else that does this?

Comment: `nc` don't known `username` and can not send it. Only can do is to type message in format `Bob: hello`.

Comment: I want to avoid that exact thing .  I am also open to alternate programs that can achieve the same functionality.

Comment: Try to find solution in this  [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61995/chat-over-lan-from-linux-to-linux)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do something like this.

Assume **Alice** is the server. She types:

```
mawk -W interactive '$0="Alice: "$0' | nc -l -p <port_number> <ip_of_alice>
```

Then **Bob** connects to that server. He types:

```
mawk -W interactive '$0="Bob: "$0' | nc <ip_of_alice> <port_number>
```

The `mawk` lines just adds the prepending name of the person to the "chat". We need `-W interactive` to set unbuffered writes to stdout and line buffered reads from stdin.

---

Now Alice types `Hi Bob` and sees:

```
Hi Bob
```

Bob sees:

```
Alice: Hi Bob
```

Bob types `Hi Alice` and sees:

```
Alice: Hi Bob
Hi Alice
```

Alice sees:

```
Hi Bob
Bob: Hi Alice
```

Comment: nc cannot use -s and -l at the same time. the -s is not required.

Comment: I got awk: option `-W interactive' unrecognized, ignored

Comment: @zt1983811 you need GNU `awk`, not `mawk`.

Comment: @chaos I did use awk awk -W interactive '$0="Alice: "$0' | nc -lvk ip port ;    ls -al /usr/bin/awk 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jun 27 06:48 /usr/bin/awk -> /etc/alternatives/awk

Comment: @zt1983811 default is mawk, use `apt-get install gawk` to install GNU awk. awk will then point to GNU awk.

Comment: @chaos I do not think it is still working, I even tried following:     

gawk -W interactive '$0="Alice: "$0' | nc -lvk 10.0.5.30 4000
Listening on [10.0.5.30] (family 0, port 4000)
gawk: option `-W interactive' unrecognized, ignored

Comment: @zt1983811 This is a `mawk` option, not `gawk`. Did you try it using `mawk` explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

A bit ago, I actually made one program that enables chatting (via IP address) on lan, there must be errors I didn't really had time to maintain it but it should give you something to start.

https://github.com/Aeres-u99/ncChat

PS: I had tried adding a file sharing support as well :P