# awk: unknown option -w ignored

Tags: command-line, awk

I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665492/how-to-build-a-simple-chat-using-netcat?noredirect=1&lq=1) forum, and saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/665507/649704) answer, and though "Hey, this looks cool!".

After trying the commands, I received this error:

```
maliciouzzhd@ubuntu$ awk -W interactive '$0="maliciouzzhd: "$0' | nc 10.0.0.1 1234
awk: unknown option -W ignored

awk: can't open file $0="maliciouzzhd: "$0
 source line number 1
```

If anyone knows how to fix this error, this would be fantastic!

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. You shouldn't assign to $0, and you're missing code block braces `{}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-W` is a mawk option, and you maybe using gawk (GNU awk). Run the command with `mawk -W ...`. `mawk` is installed by default, but if `gawk` is installed, it becomes the default `awk`.